# C: Recursive sorting of linked list

Tags: c, recursion, linked-list

I'm trying to implement a recursive sorting algorithm for linked list structure. C language.

My algorithm is this:
1) find max value in list
2) remove it from the list and insert it at Head node
3) start algorithm again from next node
4) run until you reach end of list

I have something, but it doesn't 'remember' my list. I realize I'm making a mistake somewhere (probably recursive calls), but I can't understand how to fix it.

```
typedef struct Node{
int data;
struct Node* next;
} Node;

void insert(Node** head, int val)
{
        //insert at top
        Node* to_insert = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
        to_insert->data = val;
        to_insert->next = (*head);
        (*head) = to_insert;
}

Node* sort_ll(Node* head)
{
    //base case, iterated trough entire list
    if(head == NULL)
        return NULL;

    int max = 0;
    Node* tmp = head;
    Node* to_move = tmp;

    //find maximum value
    while(tmp != NULL) {
        if(tmp->data > max) {
            max = tmp->data;
            to_move = tmp;
        }
        tmp = tmp->next;
    }

    //if its currently top, leave it there
    if(to_move == head) {
        return sort_ll(head->next);
    }

    //find node with max value
    tmp = head;
    while(tmp->next != to_move) {
        tmp = tmp->next;
    }

    //cut it out from the list
    tmp->next = tmp->next->next;
    free(to_move);

    //insert value at the head of the list
    insert(&head, max);

    return sort_ll(head->next);
}

int main()
{
    Node* list = NULL;

    insert(&list, 3);
    insert(&list, 6);
    insert(&list, 7);
    insert(&list, 2);
    insert(&list, 1);
    insert(&list, 5);
    insert(&list, 4);

    list = sort_ll(list);

    Node* tmp = list;

    while(tmp != NULL) {
        printf("%d\n", tmp->data);
        tmp = tmp->next;
    }


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The `sort_ll` function modifies `head` (indirectly) but you don't emulate "pass by reference". I assume you do it because the function returns a `Node *`, but the problem is that `sort_ll` will *always* return `NULL`. Use a debugger, and step through the code line by line.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I was also experimenting with this signature `Node* sort_ll(Node** head)` but didn't get any better results, only different type of wrong behavior. Can you explain further please? Or provide an example?

Comment: You have three return statements in `sort_ll`. One is `return NULL;` and the two others are both `return sort_ll(...);` How can it ever return a non-NULL?

Comment: My plan was that `return NULL` line executes only when sorting is finished, however I admit to not being very good with recursion techniques. Can you provide an example of working code please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

fix like this

```
Node *sort_ll(Node* head){
    if(head == NULL || head->next == NULL)
        return head;//There is no need for processing

    int max = head->data;
    Node *prev = head;
    Node *to_move = NULL;
    Node *tmp = head->next;

    //find maximum value in rest(head->next)
    while(tmp != NULL) {
        if(tmp->data > max) {
            max = tmp->data;
            to_move = prev;//save previous node for remove link
        }
        prev = tmp;
        tmp = tmp->next;
    }

    if(to_move == NULL) {//not find in rest
        head->next = sort_ll(head->next);
        return head;
    }

    prev = to_move;
    to_move = prev->next;//max node
    prev->next = prev->next->next;//max node remove from link
    to_move->next = sort_ll(head);
    return to_move;
}
```

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks a lot! I guess what confused me was this last part, and returning `to_move` node... Thanks again!

Comment: max_node->next = sort(rest of unsorted_list); return max_node;